# Semantic versioning in WPF projects

Tags: c#, wpf, semantic-versioning

We are starting to use semantic versioning for some of our projects here, and are struggling to incorporate it into the .NET world. Semantic versioning seems to use 3 digits, a *major*, *minor* and *patch*. WPF projects in .NET use 4 digits.

When printing the version using the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` property the program will obviously return 4 digits and we would like only 3. Is there any way to achieve this? We want support for semantic versioning in our projects. I've tried just deleting the fourth digit in the *Assembly Information*, and although it does allow me to delete it, the `Version` property will always print that 4th digit. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this method in my WPF applications (although its for the fileversion rather than the assembly version - I always have these the same in my small projects):

```
public static string ReturnApplicationVersion()
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
    string versionMajor = fvi.ProductMajorPart.ToString();
    string versionMinor = fvi.ProductMinorPart.ToString();
    string versionBuild = fvi.ProductBuildPart.ToString();
    string versionPrivate = fvi.ProductPrivatePart.ToString();

    string fVersion = fvi.FileVersion;
    return versionMajor + "." + versionMinor + "." + versionBuild + "." + versionPrivate;
}
```

You can easily modify it to return just 3 numbers. If you absolutely have to have the assembly version rather than the fileversion then perhaps someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.revision(v=vs.110).aspx) the way that versioning in .NET works is `Major.Minor.Build.Revision`. You can do this without defining a revision, but note that in C#, if the revision is undefined `Version#Revision` will return `-1`. If you are using the .NET Framework it is likely worthwhile to follow their semantic versioning principles.